# Error (network unreachable) resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:7fd::1#53

Tags: server

I was trying to install dhcp3 server on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) 32-bit server. Dhcp3 server is installed, but it can't find the `dhcp3.conf` file in folder `/etc/dhcp3`.

I used the command

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

which displays this message:

```
Sep 25 08:23:05 ubuntu AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Sep 25 08:24:46 ubuntu named[1195]: error (network unreachable) resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:7fd::1#53
Sep 25 08:24:46 ubuntu named[1195]: error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:7fd::1#53
Sep 25 08:24:46 ubuntu named[1195]: error (network unreachable) resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Sep 25 08:24:46 ubuntu named[1195]: error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Sep 25 08:24:46 ubuntu named[1195]: error (network unreachable) resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:3::42#53
Sep 25 08:32:51 ubuntu NetworkManager[1097]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Sep 25 08:32:51 ubuntu NetworkManager[1097]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Sep 25 08:35:03 ubuntu kernel: [ 1213.485377] type=1400 audit(1380078303.264:33): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=820 comm="cupsd" pid=820 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
Sep 25 08:39:01 ubuntu CRON[2785]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Edit file `/etc/default/bind9`:

```
# run resolvconf?
RESOLVCONF=yes
# startup options for the server
OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"
```

And then restart bind9 :

```
# service bind9 restart
```

Comment: as other solution says, you need to restart the bind9 service (sudo systemctl restart bind9.service)

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/default/bind9` as in the answer above.

Then restart the bind9 service:

```
# service bind9 restart
```